# Coverting iphone app to universal

Tags: ios, universal

I know that there are several answers for this question, but I was not clear about the result. Here are a few questions:

1) If I created a project as an iPhone project, selecting device as iPhone in deployment info, and designed the app using universal storyboard (i.e any width and any height (600x600) ). Once the design is completed and it is run on an iPad, the UI does not look good. If that is the case then, what's the point in selecting the device as an iPhone? Am I right that when selecting the device as iPhone or iPad, Xcode will allow the app to only run on those devices?

2) Now converting iPhone app to universal app: since image resolution varies from iPhone to universal app, do we have to replace all old images with new images supporting the universal app?

3) If I have an iPhone app, the Apple team will test it, both on an iPhone as well as on an iPad. If they found the UI doesnt match the iPad, will they reject the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would imagine the UI looks just like it does on the iPhone, just enlarged to fit on the iPad. Basically this is because iPhone only apps can be run on iPads, but not vice versa.  If you change the app to a Universal app, it will try to run natively on the iPad, and may look better if you have appropriately used auto-layout and size classes.

(Optional other cause) The other option is you're running into an iOS 8 issue where if you use an storyborad or nib for the launch file, it will mistakenly make an iPhone only app work as a Universal one.  The use of Launch Screen File in iOS 8.0, 8.0.1 and 8.0.2 will make you universal.

This is a know bug and fixed in iOS 8.1, for you only option is to use assets catalog with a launch images.

Or you can add the device modifier in the Launch file name, like `<launchNib>~iphone.nib`

2. As far as images go, you will want to make sure you have images for the different resolutions (@1x, @2x, @3x).  If you haven't already, I recommend reading up on asset catalogs (http://schlu.org/2013/10/01/Xcode-Asset-Catalogs.html). Images are not inherently different between iPhone and iPad (except for launch images), but it's the pixel density that really matters (older devices are 1x, most retina devices are @2x, and the 6 Plus is @3x).
3. If it is truly just an iPhone app, Apple will not reject the app because it looks pixelated and ugly on an iPad.  The ability to run iPhone only apps on iPads stems from the initial release of the iPad when people hadn't created iPad or Universal apps yet.  Apple basically provides it if someone REALLY wants an app that hasn't been created to specifically support the iPad yet.

That said, I would just go ahead and release it as a universal app.  If you don't have revenue reasons for creating separate apps, I wouldn't recommend the extra hassle of having two apps.  If course, if your app doesn't make sense on the iPad, simply make it iPhone only.

Comment: Not separate projects.  Some people have a financial reason to have separate APPS.  You can create two different apps using two targets in a single project.  If you want to sell your iPad app and get paid in addition to your iPhone app, you'd need to do it this way.  Most people, as I said, should create a single, universal app.

Answer (score 0):

These are the common practices according to your questions

1. User interface doesn't depend on deployment devices. **User interface depends on your implemented UI logic**. As you said, default storyboard size is 600x600 (this could be easily changed), but this doesn't mean, that all devices should be this resolution. When the resolution is different, images and UI elements are misplaced. There are several ways to implement UI logic and make UI flexible, but I guess your question is not about that. So, short answer - devices selections are more about deployment than UI.
2. It might be some different images for different devices, but **images such as buttons or text fields or etc should be flexible**.
3. No, **Apple doesn't care about your application appearance and design**.

I hope I have answered to your questions.

Comment: Hey Tom, Thanks for the answer, then what is the point in selecting the device in deployment info ?  Dont you feel it is bit confusing?

Comment: You will get used to it. Are you developing application for iPhone only? Maybe for iPad? Or even both? This should be a criteria to choose deployment device. Also, you might change it in general project settings.

Comment: Actually, the deployment should control what devices an app can be installed on.  The problem is a combination of the fact that iPhone apps CAN be installed on iPads and a bug in iOS 8 that confuses apps that use nibs or storyboards with Universal apps, causing them to not display as an iPhone app on the iPad.  See the optional answer for item 1 in my answer above.

Comment: Yes. You can provide different User Interface logic for both iPad and iPhone. And this would make app interactive. Without duplicating code...

Comment: Also, I would have to disagree with your answer on #3 a bit.  Apple has and can reject your app for a poor user experience / UI.  Especially if that UI does not feel at home in the iOS ecosystem.  The won't reject you, though, for having a blown up version of the iPhone app running on the iPad, since Apple is the one who allowed that in the first place.  a Universal app, however, will be tested on the iPad and a bad experience could get you rejected.

Comment: Hey wottle, you mean to say that ,if i release a iphone only version app, apple team will test it on ipad, if they found  ugly UI on the ipad, they will reject the app? I am pretty clear about the universal app, and this holds good for apple team to test app on both iphone and ipad because we mentioned that we need an universal app.

Comment: @wottle there are tons of apps whose UI is not perfect apple-style. Whatever, peace! Have a nice day!

Comment: @RockandRoll I was saying that Apple WON'T reject you for the fact that your iPhone-only app will not look great blown up on an iPad screen.  If it is Universal, Apple will test it on both devices and the app should at least have a functional UI on both. Tom, I agree, but just because others did it and made it into the store doesn't mean you can't get rejected.  There are apps in tthe store that are simply web views shells, which Apple exlicitly prohibits.  I wouldn't want to build my app that way with the assumption that they won't reject me.